# Unity in 11.04 has crashed (no launcher or dash access anymore)

Tags: 11.04, unity, ccsm

I upgraded to Ubuntu 11.04 with unity (a very bad move) and then installed advanced CCSM and deactivated the desktop wall and ticked the desktop cube. Upon pressing OK, I cannot access anything. Not the dash nor the launcher ... nothing.

I do not know what to do know ... I cannot open the terminal.

Please help me!

I am new to Ubuntu .... only a month old user... I sadly upgraded to 11.04 yesterday .... If you're reading this from a 10.10 .... do not upgrade ... bad business.

Answer (score 3):

Try executing `unity --replace`. Even if the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> dialog does not appear, it could still be running.  What graphics card/drivers are you using?

Answer (score 0):

try to launch a terminal or so and execute `unity &`. This should launch everything.
Because this problem occurs pretty often i made a keyboard shortcut for this command e.g.: Super + Alt + u.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot guys.

I managed it .... what I did (for future readers), I made a desktop launcher (shortcut) and assigned it to the Gnu-terminal inside /usr/bin/

I then used the shortcut to access the terminal, went to /usr/bin and typed ccsm to access compiz configure. One can also do as mentioned in the above posts.

By the way, after a couple of days of using Unity .... I guess it has the potential to be great .... but not just yet.

Another thing that I didn't know is that one can access the Ubuntu classic from the log screen to access the Gnome GUI.

Thanks again for the posters

Hisham ElSafti

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and this is what I did:

1. Right click on your desktop and choose **Create Launcher...**
2. Enter the following in the dialog box:
   **Type:** Application in Terminal
   **Name:** Reset Unity (you can use anything here)
   **Command:** unity --reset
   **Comment:** (anything)

   [image: Screenshot]
3. Now double click on the link to open it in a terminal window.
4. When everything is done (when your bars are back) restart your computer.